# How to get previous and next date compared to an array of dates in PHP

Tags: php, date

How to get previous and next date compared the current date to an array of dates. 
 I have dates in string format to compare the current date and return previous and next date from dates

current date today like `16, Oct 2018 20:02`

```
foreach($arraydates as $date) { 
    echo date('d, M Y H:i', $date) . '<br>';
}
```

output dates

```
02, Oct 2018 06:26<br>
09, Oct 2018 05:47<br>
18, Oct 2018 20:02<br>
24, Oct 2018 18:47<br>
31, Oct 2018 17:42<br>
07, Nov 2018 17:02<br>
```

returning result should be like

```
09, Oct 2018 05:47<br>
18, Oct 2018 20:02<br>
```

Comment: Have you considered using strtotime so it's easy to sort?

Comment: yes i have all dates in strtotime string dates how please give a example

Comment: SO you just want the date a week ago and the date in a weeks time right? Do we have to use an array?

Comment: yes like case sensitive if one-minute difference have and include previous or next date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider`$arrayDates` is ordered in ascending order.

```
<?php
$currentDate = strtotime("16, Oct 2018 12:00");
$prevDate;
$nextDate;

foreach($arrayDates as $date){
    $date = strtotime($date);
    if($date < $currentDate) {
        $prevDate = $date;
    }
    if($date > $currentDate){
        $nextDate = $date;
        break;
    }
}
?>
```

The previous date is stored in `$prevDate` and the next date is stored in `$nextDate`